# Make a negative number positive python

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column df with mix of positive and negative number, as mentioned below:

```
Value
100
564
-789
3637
-999
```

I want to make a new df by adding the number 3600 to the ONLY negative value and my new df should have values like:

```
Value
100
564
2811
3637
2601
```

Please help me with the python code for this.

Comment: `np.where(df['Value'].lt(0), df['Value'].add(3600), df['Value'])` lots of ways to do this, not sure it warrants a question as its basic if/where filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['a']<0, 'a'] += 3600
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be written as follow:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([100,564, -789, 3637, -999])
x[x < 0] = x[x < 0] + 3600
    
print(x)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
df['Value'] = [n+3600 if n < 0 else n for n in df['Value']]
```

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish this we can loop through the list for each number and if the number is less than 0 then add in 3600. Here is the code for this:

```
values = [100, 564, -789, 3637, -999]
for value in values:
  if value < 0:
    value += 3600
```

This is the code. To print out the result, just run:

```
print(values)
```